# -eclipse- I can not Find the layout xml in the layout folder

Tags: eclipse

I start Eclipse after a long time. I had tried to make an Android application project and made all the options right but when I open ( res/layout ) there is nothing there. Every application I made in the folder is empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's not created by default.  If you need an XML folder, you'll need to create one.

It should be pointed out that it's not really necessary.  It's just a matter of helping you keep your stuff organized.

Comment: But in the tutorials I can see the program make it when just make a new project !

Comment: Maybe when the tutorial was made that was the case.  But the version I have does not create it.  In any case, the answer is correct.  Just make it yourself.

Comment: please can help me because i did not find a Activity for this layout ?

Comment: Seriously...  Whatever that folder and file, should be there according to the tutorial, just create it.  Then follow the tutorial for what should BE in that file.